# Keras: model with one input and two outputs, trained jointly on different data (semi-supervised learning)

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, unsupervised-learning

I would like to code with Keras a neural network that acts both as an autoencoder AND a classifier for semi-supervised learning. Take for example this dataset where there is a few labeled images and a lot of unlabeled images: https://cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/stl10/

Some papers listed [here](http://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/classification_datasets_results.html#53544c2d3130) achieved that, or very similar things, successfully.

To sum up: if the model would have the same input data shape and the same "encoding" convolutional layers, but would split into two heads (fork-style), so there is a classification head and a decoding head, in a way that the unsupervised autoencoder will contribute to a good learning for the classification head.

With TensorFlow there would be no problem doing that as we have full control over the computational graph.

But with Keras, things are more high-level and I feel that all the calls to ".fit" must always provide all the data at once (so it would force me to tie together the classification head and the autoencoding head into one time-step).

One way in keras to almost do that would be with something that goes like this:

```
input = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
cnn_feature_map = sequential_cnn_trunk(input)

classification_predictions = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(cnn_feature_map)

autoencoded_predictions = decode_cnn_head_sequential(cnn_feature_map)

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[classification_predictions, ])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([images], [labels, images], epochs=10)
```

However, I think and I fear that if I just want to fit things in that way it will fail and ask for the missing head:

```
for epoch in range(10):
    # classifications step
    model.fit([images], [labels, None], epochs=1)
    # "semi-unsupervised" autoencoding step
    model.fit([images], [None, images], epochs=1)
    # note: ".train_on_batch" could probably be used rather than ".fit" to avoid doing a whole epoch each time.
```

How should one implement that behavior with Keras? And could the training be done jointly without having to split the two calls to the ".fit" function?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you don't have a label you can pass zero vector instead of one hot encoded vector. It should not change your result because zero vector doesn't have any error signal with categorical cross entropy loss.

My custom to_categorical function looks like this:

```
def tricky_to_categorical(y, translator_dict):
    encoded = np.zeros((y.shape[0], len(translator_dict)))
    for i in range(y.shape[0]):
        if y[i] in translator_dict:
            encoded[i][translator_dict[y[i]]] = 1
    return encoded
```

When y contains labels, and translator_dict is a python dictionary witch contains labels and its unique keys like this:

`{'unisex':2, 'female': 1, 'male': 0}`

If an UNK label can't be found in this dictinary then its encoded label will be a zero vector

If you use this trick you also have to modify your accuracy function to see real accuracy numbers. you have to filter out all zero vectors from our metrics

```
def tricky_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    mask = K.not_equal(K.sum(y_true, axis=-1), K.constant(0))  # zero vector mask
    y_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, mask)
    y_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask)
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)), K.floatx())
```

note: You have to use larger batches (e.g. 32) in order to prevent zero matrix update, because It can make your accuracy metrics crazy, I don't know why

**Alternative solution**

Use Pseudo Labeling :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean at the bottom (about batches). Are you saying that in a given batch, every item must be unlabeled (0 mask) or all items in the batch must be labeled?

Comment: Some "one hot" encoded labels can be zero vectors (because we don't know the correct label). We don't want an update where all labels are zero vectors in a batch (0 matrix), because I don't know why it can cause some metrics problem in keras. At least one of labels must have information, should not be a zero vector

Answer (score 0):

you can train jointly, you have to pass an array insted of single label.

I used fit_generator, e.g.

```
model.fit_generator(
batch_generator(),
steps_per_epoch=len(dataset) / batch_size,
epochs=epochs)


def batch_generator():
batch_x = np.empty((batch_size, img_height, img_width, 3))
gender_label_batch = np.empty((batch_size, len(gender_dict)))
category_label_batch = np.empty((batch_size, len(category_dict)))
while True:
    i = 0
    for idx in np.random.choice(len(dataset), batch_size):
        image_id = dataset[idx][0]
        batch_x[i] = load_and_convert_image(image_id)
        gender_label_batch[i] = gender_labels[idx]
        category_label_batch[i] = category_labels[idx]

        i += 1
    yield batch_x, [gender_label_batch, category_label_batch]
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the two labels at the same time. For example, with an X I will have only Y_1, and for another X, I have both Y_1 and Y_2. But the thing is I can't always give the two outputs at once. Anyway, if I plan to do that it will be with another library in the end.

Comment: now I see yout problem, dont worry I also have a (own) solution for this:) You need a custom to_categorical and a custom accuracy function. Tomorrow I will post a detailed answer, the main idea is that when you dont have label you should pass zero vector insted of one hot vector. In this case you dont have any error signal, and thats it.